# How to install and use PyQt5 in Linux

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pyqt5

In Ubuntu I installed PyQt via pip

```
pip3 install PyQt5
```

However, my script still says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

> File "/media/storage/Python/my_app.py", line 11, in 
>       from mainwindow import *   File "/media/storage/Python/mainwindow.py", line 4, in 
>       from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
>
> **ImportError: No module named PyQt5**

Then I tried from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

and got that it is installed:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pyqt5 is already the newest version (5.7+dfsg-5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How to convince PyCharm 2017.1 to use PyQt5? I just realized it works if I run it from terminal:

```
python3 my_script.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you need to set the correct interpreter in PyCharm. 
To do this you can go in

```
Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter
```

and here choose the correct one in the select at the top of the window.

After this you should see the `PyQt` in the list below. Then click on `Apply` and try to run again your script.